# EDS analysis with 15kV

Tags: material-science

If I collect an EDS X-ray spectrum from a sample of TiO2 at 15 kV accelerating voltage and X-ray count of 30,000 cps. As well as the Ti Kα and Ti Kβ peaks at 4.51 and 4.93 keV respectively, and I see there a small peak visible in the spectrum at 2.77 keV.
What should be the reason to see this small peak? Is it just because of escape peak or there is any other reasons to see this peak?

Comment: The search term is ‘escape peak’.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have asked that already

Comment: So you’ve been pointed to the escape peak yet discount it apparently. What are you really asking then?

Comment: I am just asking whether I am right or wrong about the escape peak? Is it the escape peak or any other thing I am missing?